# Add to array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, the value of the first element is 1.

Every time a user clicks a button, I want it to increase by 1. 
I have this written, but it's making the array element go from 1, to 11, to 111... and so on. How do I just get it to increase by 1. Like 1, 2, 3...

```
function addCake (){
    quantityArray[0] += 1;
    var cost= quantityArray[0] * 1.49;
    document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML += "<tr id="+"cakeTotal"+"><td>"+quantityArray[0]+"</td>Cake Donut</td><td>"+"$"+cost+"</td>";
}
```

Comment: How and when are you initializing this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert it to int

```
quantityArray[0] = parseInt(quantityArray[0]);
quantityArray[0] += 1;
```

---

The problem I see is that you are initalizating the array items as `""`.

Why? if you set as `0`, you can avoid the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rgvaT/2/

```
quantityArray[0]=0;
```

Comment: i think you need to edit it to `parseInt(quantityArray[0])` because 1 is int by default.

Comment: this would probably work, but it starts at 0, so it's giving me NaN

Comment: @Ktown Ah! can you post some more code? like on a fiddle? It would be easier to write the precise code you need that way

Comment: @Ktown Edited the answer with your fiddle

Answer (score 3):

Change your code as below :

```
function addCake (){
    quantityArray[0]=parseInt(quantityArray[0]) + 1;
    var cost= parseInt(quantityArray[0]) * 1.49;
    document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML += "<tr id="+"cakeTotal"+"><td>"+quantityArray[0]+"</td>Cake Donut</td><td>"+"$"+cost+"</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
quantityArray[0]++;
```

This will also add 1 to your counter.

Answer (score 2):

No need to call parseInt etc. Just initialize your `quantityArray` array properly:

```
var quantityArray = [];
quantityArray[0] = 0;

function addCake (){
    quantityArray[0]++;
    var cost = quantityArray[0] * 1.49;
    document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML += "<tr id="+"cakeTotal"+"><td>"+quantityArray[0]+"</td>Cake Donut</td><td>"+"$"+cost+"</td>";
}
```

Comment: @ktown: Dont initialize your array element like this: `quantityArray[0]="";`. As I suggested above make it `quantityArray[0]=0;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
quantityArray[0]=parseInt(quantityArray[0]) + 1;
```

Comment: Does `1` require parseInt?

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = new Array();
    test[0] = 1;
    test[0] += 1;
    test[0] += 1;
alert(test[0]); // output is 3. Its working fine.
```

What you are doing is concatenating the "String" 1 with previous value of array.

To avoid that cast the value to int, using parseInt(). Something like this.

```
function addCake (){
    quantityArray[0] += parseInt(1, 10); // To decimal. It is very important
    var cost= quantityArray[0] * 1.49;
    document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML += "<tr id="+"cakeTotal"+"><td>"+quantityArray[0]+"</td>Cake Donut</td><td>"+"$"+cost+"</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have initialized the array element as string.
use below code to increment the element .

```
quantityArray[0] = parseInt(quantityArray[0]) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here The Problem is with They datatype**

In **JavaScript**, when you declare a variable by `var x;`  It stores the variable as an object of type var.That is what causing the problem.

> You need to Convert the object ( var ) to an integer to do
>   mathematical operations by type casting. You can typecast using
>   (Number) function. In other cases it consider `+` as an **append
>   operator** and variables as **String** do append function.

The code will looks like this.

```
function addCake (){
    quantityArray[0] =(Number)quantityArray[0]+1;
    var cost= quantityArray[0] * 1.49;
    document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML += "<tr id="+"cakeTotal"+"><td>"+quantityArray[0]+"</td>Cake Donut</td><td>"+"$"+cost+"</td>";
}
```